# Arduino IDE: esptool.FatalError: Invalid head of packet

Tags: arduino, esp8266, android-wifi, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to connect my ESP8266 Module and I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSMgi.jpg) when I do so. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAq3n.jpg) is the wiring that I have set up (ignore the 3 crossed out wires at the bottom). Do you know how I can address this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

hello when you connect to the module
esp8266 of:
Push button on reset pin 1
Push the button on the 2 flash pins
Release the button on the 3 reset pins
Release the button on the 4 flash pins
Follow the steps it will be fixed.